# Xamarin iOS TableView with custom class

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have a TableView which is on a normal View, which is on a ViewController. 
I have a Class called TableViewController and i want the TableView to use this Class. However, it doesnt enter the TableViewController Class. And yes, i set the property "class" to TableViewController.

My code (TableViewController.cs)

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UIKit;

namespace Blogger
{
public partial class TableViewController : UITableView
{

    public List<String> Tests { get; set; }

    public TableViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        Tests.Add("Jörg");
        Tests.Add("Carsten");
    }


    [Export("numberOfSectionsInTableView:")]
    public int NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    [Export("tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:")]
    public nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return (nint)Tests.Count;
    }

    [Export("tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:")]
    public string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        return "Header";
    }

    [Export("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")]
    public void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

    }

    [Export("tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:")]
    public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        var cell = new UITableViewCell();

        cell.TextLabel.Text = Tests[indexPath.Row];

        return cell;
    }



}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Is your "TableView" off type UIView or UITableView?

Comment: yeah, sry. code added

Comment: The View, on which the TableView is, has "UIView" set as class.

The TableView has "TableViewController" set as class.